# Meteor Javascript Uncaught ReferenceError: Package is not defined

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am new Meteor and have recently been working on a starter project. Everything was going just fine and was halfway through when all of a sudden Meteor stopped working. However, I am have a lot of trouble pinpointing what is wrong.

My console still reads

```
[[[[[ ~/Desktop/Coding/Meteor/mine ]]]]]      

=> Started proxy.                             
=> Started MongoDB.                           
=> Started your app.                          

=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/
```

However, when I open the Chrome console I am getting

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Package is not defined(anonymous function)
```

These packages are defined for us by Meteor and I have not touched them once (nor do I know how to). Can someone help point me in the right direction? I tried re-installing Meteor as well as starting a new sample project and I am still getting the same errors in the console.

Comment: Expand the error in the console and paste the whole traceback here.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: Package is not defined(anonymous function)    @ meteor.js?9730f4ff059088b3f7f14c0672d155218a1802d4:14(anonymous function) @ meteor.js?9730f4ff059088b3f7f14c0672d155218a1802d4:1102
meteor-base.js?f0836ed3757e6217fff6e2710a1293407a6d9b09:14 Uncaught ReferenceError: Package is not defined(anonymous function) @ meteor-base.js?f0836ed3757e6217fff6e2710a1293407a6d9b09:14(anonymous function) @ meteor-base.js?f0836ed3757e6217fff6e2710a1293407a6d9b09:22

Comment: hmm, can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: I'm not sure if you are familiar with http://meteortips.com/book.pdf but if I start from scratch with the basic starter code that displays the "Welcome to Meteor" message I still get the same problem. All it takes to get this starter project is to install meteor and then just create a barebones project using 'meteor create applicationName'

Comment: Actually, the Uncaught ReferenceError I listed above is only small subset of those errors. It doesn't seem to be finding any of the Javascript files/packages. It's a very strange error. It was working perfectly fine this afternoon.

Comment: See if you can run your code on meteorpad.com

Comment: Ok. So I just tried it in Incognito and also in Safari. It works in both of those. Does Chrome have some sort of weird caching mechanism?

Comment: This usually happens when one of the packages used in a project initializes with errors. Try removing packages you manually added to the project one-by-one.

Comment: Well that's the thing with Meteor. It handles everything for you. I didn't manually include any packages or files. All I did was create a Meteor Project and Meteor initializes all necessary files for you (.html, .css, .js) as well as any necessary js packages in the background. This is for a very simple web app. I'm sure you could include other packages as you grow it to something more complex.